# Filter JavaScript variable and get content from H3?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a **JS** variable which contains HTML code with tags.

My question is how can I filter this variable and get only H3 tag content?

I tried it with following methods...

```
var api_el_title = $(my_full_content).text('h3');
var api_el_title = $(my_full_content).filter('h3');
var api_el_title = $(my_full_content ).find('h3');
```

No one is able to display only H3 content.

Example output of a variable is:

```
<h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
<p>Dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Amet ist</p>
<p>Dolor sit ipsum</p>
```

Comment: You'll have to show what `my_full_content` contains.

Comment: @Juhana this return me html... with his h3 tag etc...

Comment: You still have to show it. The answer depends on the structure of the HTML.

Comment: @Juhana the output is following: http://pastebin.com/MGBbwj7J

Comment: Any reason you couldn't paste those 4 lines to the question? Anyway, the HTML doesn't have any h3 tags.

Comment: @Juhana sorry, now is in the post description.

Comment: @jExchange, Your edit had added few more complications in your question...

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Pass handler function in `filter` and test the tag using [**`Element.tagName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) property.

```js
var ip = '<h1>Hey</h1>\
<h3>Valid</h3>\
<h2>Hello</h2>\
<h1>Hey</h1>\
<h3>Valid</h3>\
<h2>Hello</h2>';
var filtered = $(ip).filter(function() {
  return this.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'h3';
});
$('body').append(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find to find all h3 ,use each to loop and store each value of the h3 element

```
var my_full_content = '<h3>Lorem ipsum</h3><p>Dolor sit amet</p><p>Amet ist</p><h3>Lorem ipsum2</h3><p>Dolor sit ipsum</p>'
var text = [];
$('<div>'+my_full_content+'</div>').find('h3').each(function(i,v){
   text.push($(v).text());
});
alert(text);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f0chx41c/

Answer (score -1):

**Just as a note, your question is very vague.**

Assuming that you've got access to JQuery and with the limited information that you've provided, the following could be a solution:

```
function doWork(my_full_content) //SEND YOUR HTML VARIABLE TO THIS FUNCTION
{
    //CREATE INVISIBLE PLACEHOLDER DIV
    $('body').append('<div id="tmpPlaceholder" style="display:none"></div>');

    // PLACE HTML INTO TEMPORARY DIV THAT IS HIDDEN
    $("#tmpPlaceholder").append(my_full_content); 

    //SHOWS THE h3's CONTENT
    var hContent = $("#tmpPlaceholder").find("h3").first().html();
    alert(hContent);

    $("#tmpPlaceholder").remove();
}
```

## EDIT

This would work if the **my_full_content** variable is a string.